# How to do pagination using java in play framework?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, pagination, playframework-2.0

I am doing **pagination** in my web app so how to do this ?

what i want is : i wan to show all the users to admin!

i went through this play framework computer app [computer-database](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/samples/java/computer-database) but i don't want this type of pagination
`computer -database` app pagination is :

[image]

but i want like google :

[image]

my query same like `computer-database` app:

**model part of user**

```
public static Page<User> page(int page, int pageSize, String sortBy, String order, String filter) {
        return 
            find.where()
                .ilike("name", "%" + filter + "%")
                .orderBy(sortBy + " " + order)
                .findPagingList(pageSize)
                .getPage(page);
    }
```

**view is:**

[adm.scala.html](http://en.textsave.org/6VK)

and **contoller** is :

```
public static Result enter() {
        Form<Login> loginForm = Form.form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();

        if (loginForm.hasErrors()) {
            return badRequest(logi.render(loginForm));// errorsAsJson());
        }

        if(loginForm.get().email.equals("admin@admin.com") ) {

            return redirect(routes.paging.pag(0, "name", "asc", ""));

        }
```

and **paging.java**

```
public class paging extends Controller {

    public static Result pag(int page, String sortBy, String order, String filter) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

return ok(adm.render(User.page(page, 2, sortBy, order, filter),
                sortBy, order, filter));

    }
```

Give me some idea for that pagination.

Answer (score 2):

You can use paginate module on play, [try this](http://www.playframework.com/modules/paginate-head/home)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at it http://www.kev009.com/wp/2012/12/reusable-pagination-in-play-2/  it's written in scala but it with little effort can be done in java

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... the easiest way is check the [API for Ebean's Page class](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/Page.html) it has ie. `getTotalPageCount()` method, so you can easily iterate from 0 to *count of pages* to generate links for every page of results (prev/next arrows removed to keep sample clean...)

```
<div id="pagination2" class="pagination">
    <ul>
        @for(i <- 0 until currentPage.getTotalPageCount()){
            <li><a  href="@link(i, null)">@(i+1)</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

*This code refers to the [mentioned sample - list view](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/samples/java/computer-database/app/views/list.scala.html).*

Comment: could you please tell me how is getting total page. what is logic behind this?

Comment: @RahulKulhari it just performs additional query like: `select count(*) ...` of course it contains all conditions placed in the original. You don't need to do it manually, mentioned method does it in the background.

Comment: @biesior link is not working anymore. Please update it.

Comment: @saurav indeed, samples were removed since 2.3 branch of Play and replaced by Activator's templates and/or seeds - code mentioned in the answer is available in `Computer Database Scala` template now.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my pagination sample code:**

Here

**count** is total data in database,

**skip** is how many data have been skipped in  call,

**lengthOfElement** is how many data have been pulled,

**collect** is how many data in maximum will be pulled in per query,

```
 @(count:Int, skip:Int, lengthOfElement:Int, collect:Int)

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
        <div class="dataTables_info" id="DataTables_Table_0_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">total
            @count
            entries, showing till @{skip+lengthOfElement}th
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
        <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="DataTables_Table_0_paginate">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="paginate_button page-item  @if(skip==0){disabled}else{}" id="DataTables_Table_0_previous">
                    <a href="@student.routes.AllStudentsController.allStudents(skip-collect)" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0"
                       class="page-link">
                        Previous
                    </a>
                </li>

                @for(i<-0 until count/collect+(if(count%collect!=0){1}else{0})){
                <li class="paginate_button page-item @if(skip==i*collect){active}else{}">
                    <a href="@student.routes.AllStudentsController.allStudents(i*collect)" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0"
                       class="page-link">
                        @{i+1}
                    </a>
                </li>
                }

                <li class="paginate_button page-item  @if(lengthOfElement<collect || skip+collect==count){disabled}else{}" id="DataTables_Table_0_next">
                    <a href="@student.routes.AllStudentsController.allStudents(skip+collect)" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0"
                       class="page-link">
                        Next
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```